# BootStrap DatePicker Calendar Input Change Not Updating Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have an input element with an attached datepicker created using bootstrap-datepicker.
When the user changes the date by typing directly into the input element, and then clicks the calendar icon, the changed date is not reflected in the calendar

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">

    <div class="input-append date" id="calendar_toDate" data-date="12/31/2999" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"><input type="Text" alt="toDate" id="toDate" name="toDate" enabled="" onblur="Javascript:checkDate(this, '', 'R');" value="12/31/2999" size="10" maxlength="10" class="input input-small" data-req="Y" aria-required="true" data-type="d">

<span class="add-on" title="Date Picker"><i class="icon icon-calendar"></i></span> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){ 
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint(); 
    $('#calendar_toDate').datepicker(); 
    }); 
    function calenderDataChange(){
    javascript:dataChangeCheckRoleDate();} 
    $('#calendar_toDate').datepicker({ 
    format : 'mm/dd/yyyy', 
    startDate:'01/01/1900', 
    endDate:'12/31/2999', 
    autoClose:true ,
    orientation:'auto right' 
    }).on('changeDate',function(ev){ 
    $(this).datepicker('hide'); 
    }); 
    </script> 
    <span class="required"></span>

    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i have a framework restriction, the code snippet i posted is created by the framework itself, i couldnt change much of that, maybe i can add some JS functions to those.

Is there a way, i can make it work, with current setup?